# Create my own, local-only email, @example.com?

Tags: email, home-server

I'd like to have a little in-house e-mail server.  Doesn't need to broadcast to the Internet.  I noticed that when I get onto a web host, they often offer an unlimited number of @example.com e-mail addresses via cpanel.  Because I want to experiment with that in testing, I'm wondering if anyone could tell me how to set it up on my machine?  I'm using XP and Apache.

Comment: This might be more involved then you think. If you want it for the whole network your going to need DNS as well.

Comment: It sounds like what you want is a stand-alone POP3 or IMAP4 server. I don't know Apache sorry, so I'm not sure if there's a piece of companion software to it that runs those things on Windows XP. Still, maybe search on "Windows POP3 server XP" or similar. Good luck! Also you don't need DNS if you only have a few clients or just one. Just use IP addresses.

Comment: I remember [hMailServer](http://www.hmailserver.com/) and [MDaemon](http://www.altn.com/products/mdaemon-email-server-windows/) being suggested in various places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download XAMPP from http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html. Their stack includes a Mercury Mail server which will do exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: That's what I was thinking... that there was something built into xampp.

Comment: Yep - Mercury Mail will run as a service and do the basics, enough to simulate what you need.

Comment: Are you sure you meant FireZilla? FileZilla comes with XAMPP and is an excellent SFTP/file server solution. All I saw for FireZilla (besides Pokemon) is a XUL download manager project on SourceForge.

Comment: Thunderbird, ionstar?  That's what I meant....  My mistake.  It's a useful tool for localhost-to-localhost e-mails.